# Monitoring low level hooks [C]

Tags: c, windows, keyboard

Is there any kind of way to monitor the low level keyboard hooks in a Windows enviroment. Say if I am making a program trying to find keyloggers.

Comment: @arsane: I tried but couldn't find anything to *monitor* the hooks; the official API only allows to add and remove a hook, you can't get a list of installed hooks. So can you give me the query you used, please?

Comment: I thought you mention key logger. It seems that you mean how to find key loggers, that's a really hard to answer problem. You can take this http://www.hellboundhackers.org/articles/155-the-art-of-keylogging-implementation-and-detection.html as start, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

*> There is no official API to query the installed keyboard hooks.*

Yes, there are. (you're too young to know this...)
You must read the PEB.
See on [Win32 api Group](http://news://nntp.aioe.org/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32)
where all the Windows source code (each api, undocumented or not ) had been disassembled

Comment: Perhaps this link might be more useful: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32/topics

Answer (score 0):

[Discussion about reading hooks](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-327312.html)

A problem you might run into is that there are malware that do not exist as "processes" that you can enumerate easily.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official API to query the installed keyboard hooks. Since MicroSoft doesn't share the source for Windows, you must install a keyboard hook and single step the assembler code to figure out where Windows is saving this information. Then, you can write a device driver that watches this memory area for changes.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem is that at least one keylogger works by injecting itself into the keyboard's processor memory and running from there. Almost impossible to detect and if you can, you'll have to know a lot about how keyboards work.

Summary: If you have success with this task in any way, you will probably not cover all possible keyloggers. Bad news, I'm afraid.